# How to get favicon.ico from a website using Java?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, ico

So I'm making an application to store shortcuts to all the user's favorite applications, acting kind of like a hub. I can have support for actual files and I have a `.lnk` parser for shortcuts. I thought it would be pretty good for the application to support Internet shortcuts, too. This is what I'm doing:

Suppose I'm trying to get [Google's icon](http://www.google.com/favicon.ico) (`http://www.google.com/favicon.ico`).

1. I start out by getting rid of the extra pages (e.g. `www.google.com/anotherpage` would become `www.google.com`.
2. Then, I use `ImageIO.read(java.net.URL)` to get the Image.

The problem is that `ImageIO` never returns an Image when I call this method:

```
String trimmed = getBaseURL(page); //This removes the extra pages
Image icon = null;    
try {
    String fullURLString = trimmed + "/favicon.ico";
    URL faviconURL = new URL(fullURLString);
    icon = ImageIO.read(faviconURL);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return icon;
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Does Java support the ICO format even though it is from Microsoft?
2. Why does `ImageIO` fail to read from the URL?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

Comment: @HunterMcMillen No, can you explain that a bit?

Comment: are you sure that 'getBaseURL()' removes the last String too? If not, you are trying to get the image from www.google.com//favicon.ico.

Comment: @11684 Yes, The URL's path is `http://www.google.com/favicon.ico`.

Comment: @whowantsakookie Well if none of the registered Image readers can read that format, you will get null returned. As mentioned in the page Beau is trying to link to. link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29 for some reason I get a 404 on his link

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I got a 404...

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Me too. Chrome doesn't like that link, but Firefox does.

Comment: @whowantsakookie That's weird, but yes I am using Firefox

Comment: I meant the last /, but I think you understood me already

Comment: I noticed that the URL class does not have a constructor with a signature `URL(java.net.URL)`. How is that compiling for you?

Comment: @user845279 Oh sorry, just a copy and past problem. That was supossed to be `new URL(fullURLString)`. I'll change that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Image4J](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/).

As this quick Scala REPL session shows (paste-able as Java code):

```
> net.sf.image4j.codec.ico.ICODecoder.read(new java.net.URL("http://www.google.com/favicon.ico").openStream())

res1: java.util.List[java.awt.image.BufferedImage] = [BufferedImage@65712a80: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 16 height = 16 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0]
```

---

**UPDATE**

To answer your questions: Does Java support ICO? Doesn't seem like it:

```
> javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.net.URL("http://www.google.com/favicon.ico"))

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty region!
```

Why does `ImageIO` fail to read from the URL? Well, the URL itself seems to work for me, so you may have a proxy/firewall issue, or it could be the problem above.

Comment: @opyate It's a [bug](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=cf757a2e4d6ffffffff9113c0c3c674747?bug_id=6633448) in Java. ImageIO class tries to use `WBMPImageReader` as an ico parser but fails. The issue is documented with a couple of other formats (.mov for example). According to the bug report, the issue is fixed as of 7(b63). The workaround was to disable `WBMPImageReader`.

Comment: Note that the code here will not work in all situations because ICODecoder (0.7, released in 2008 but still not updated) has a critical bug with how it reads from an InputStream, not checking the return value from read() (or checking it, and doing the wrong thing.) Using BufferedInputStream *may* avoid the situation, but I can't be sure whether read() from BufferedInputStream will return the data every time either, so I think the better thing to do is to read the entire icon into a byte[] and then give ICODecoder a ByteArrayInputStream.

Answer (score 5):

Old post, but for future reference:

I've written a plugin for ImageIO that adds support for .ICO (MS Windows Icon) and .CUR (MS Windows Cursor) formats.

You can get it from GitHub here: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/

After you have [installed](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/#installing) the plugin, you should be able to read the icon, using the code in the original post without any modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need ImageIO for this. Just copy the bytes, same as for any other static resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is Apache Commons Imaging for reading ico files and others: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/index.html

Reading an ico file works like this:

```
List<BufferedImage> images = org.apache.commons.imaging.Imaging.getAllBufferedImages(yourIcoFile);
```

In your case you have to download it first, I guess.