# Unable to load image from the same package in Java?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

In my java package, I have a file called 'prog.ico'. I'm trying to load this file, via the following code:

```
java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getResource("prog.ico");
java.awt.Image image = ImageIO.read( url );
System.out.println("image: " + image);
```

This gives the output:

```
image: null
```

What am I doing wrong? The .ico file exists in the same package as the class from which I'm running this code.

Comment: what's the result of `file.exists()`?

Comment: @turbo it gives false. But the file definitely exists in the same package, under the same name (prog.ico)

Comment: @turbo I checked it by making a file from the same path (by getting `url.getPath()` ) and that also gives false

Comment: have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: What's printed when you execute `System.out.println(this.getClass().getName())`? Are you sure the file exists in the same package as the one printed? How are you compiling your classes?

Comment: @turbo Trying the absolute path (by making a new `File` and passing it the absolute path, then passing this file into `ImageIO.read` also returns null, without throwing any exception. Perhaps ImageIO can't load .ico files?

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, the file definitely exists. I'm compiling in netbeans.

Comment: Check if this.getClass().getResourceAsStream() returns null. If it does, then the resource is not there. If it does not, then it's an ImageIO problem.

Comment: @JBNizet If I replace the file's name in code to a `.jpg` one in the same folder, then it loads up file. So the problem must be that `.ico` file can't be read..

Comment: I think you're right, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090508/how-to-get-favicon-ico-from-a-website-using-java

Comment: @turbo If you want to post that as answer, I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the .ico image format is not supported.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090508/how-to-get-favicon-ico-from-a-website-using-java) question and it's answer to get around this.

To prevent link rot: This solution recommends using [Image4J](http://image4j.sourceforge.net/) to process .ico files.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a plugin for ImageIO that adds support for .ICO (MS Windows Icon) and .CUR (MS Windows Cursor) formats.

You can get it from GitHub here: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-ico

After you have it [installed](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/#installing) the plugin, you should be able to read your icon using the code in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you must go over `FileInputStream`  to wrap  the file

```
 File file = new File("prog.ico"); 
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comments, just changing the file to a .jpg fixes the problem, so I think the issue is that .ico files are not supported.